# What could interfere with setting foldmethod=indent by autocmd FileType python?

Tags: autocmd, folding, filetype

So recently I noticed my `autocmd FileType python setlocal foldmethod=indent` is not working anymore. The version for my vim is 8.2

When I open a python file everything is working fine except the folding and `setlocal foldmethod?` returns `foldmethod=manual`.

`verbose set ft?` returns

```
  filetype=python                                                                                                  
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim line 1364
```

Which from this autocmd

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py,*.pyw,.pythonstartup,.pythonrc  setf python
```

`verbose setlocal foldmethod?` returns just `foldmethod=manual` and not where it is last set.

When I `set verbose=9` I do find the autocmd triggered and nothing else that sets the foldmethod.

```
Executing FileType Autocommands for "python"
autocommand setlocal foldmethod=indent
```

Anything else I can check?

edit: I found the culprit

The problem was a faulty autocmd in my vimrc.

```
let g:my_coc_file_types = ['vim', 'sh', 'python', 'tex']

autocmd FileType * if index(g:my_coc_file_types, &filetype) == -1 | let b:coc_enabled=0
```

that has to end with `| endif`

So the why and the how? Is that still an interesting question to be answered?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Is it possible that you have plug-ins to manage sessions or views and that the setting you're getting is being restored from a view? They save option values by default... And also save folds (in case of manual folds) so that might be an area where there might be interference...

Comment: In addition to @filbranden's suggestion I would do a quick search of your runtimepath for python ftplugins (thought that _should_ show up in `:verbose`) and also try `:debug edit some.py` from which you can step through every bit of code that runs. Lastly, it might be worth just dropping your `setlocal` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`—if that doesn't solve the problem, it's extremely likely to be sessions/views/something similar.